# Retrive json value from nested json which is present in pandas dataframe

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I have pandas dataframe in which one column has its entries in nested json form like this as shown below

```
Date              ID              Request

12/01/2020        123            {"requestChannel":"amazon","userID":"123@abc.com","Context":"
                                 {\"ref_id\":[\"1-123456\"],\"type\":\"Apparels\","formJson":null,"additionalData":null},"additional":
                                 {"ref_id":"1-12345","last_saved":"order"}}

and thousands of rows like this in same format
```

I want to take out just the "type" in nested second json on the basis of "ID" like this:

```
Output

Date             ID        Request

12/01/2020       123       Apparels
```

What i am trying to do is to parse the Request column of dataframe as json iterate over entire row and take the "type" key from second "Context" json and take the key type

```
for name in range(data.shape[0]):
        output_json=data['Request'][name]
        json_data=json.loads(output_json)
        try:
            parse_json=json.loads(json_data['Request'])
            value_to_insert=''
            for json_key in parse_json:
                value_to_insert+=str(json_key + '--'+ str(parse_json[json_key])+', '+'\n')
```

But my code is not changing the dataframe series to correct json form and also iterating over the entire rows is taking a lot of time. Any idea on optimized solution would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try avoiding loops. Even if you are looping use pandas's `DataFrame.iterrows` to do so. For the cases of extracting or updating `DataFrame.apply` will be best for most cases.

If Request column is of type string, then you can do

```
import json
data['Request'] = data['Request'].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x).get("Context",{}).get("type"))
```

If your Request column can be `None`, then you should do

```
import json
data['Request'] = data['Request'].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x).get("Context",{}).get("type") if x else None)
```

**Edit:**
Looks like you've a string in `Context`, You'll have to parse multiple times

```
import json
data['Request'] = data['Request'].apply(lambda x: json.loads(json.loads(x).get("Context","{}")).get("type") if x else None)
```

Comment: @jezrael Yes, in most cases. It can give you improvements if you are careful. I tend to follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-pandas-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316. I should probably change the wording a bit.

Comment: I tried the solution proposed by you however while running i got the ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'``` then I added exception to that and still it did not run for any row.

Comment: Did you get the output as expected

Comment: @SachinKumar Looks like you've string in `Context`, I've updated answer to parse twice, try that out

Comment: I tried your approach of parsing twice but its throwing json decode error ```JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)``` seems parsing twice have issues..trying to get any breakthrough to parse nested jsons